# Synchronous HTTP calls

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Dart's http library is based on async sockets. What that implies is that any http call is async.
From what I gathered, OS calls are also done asynchronously.
I have an android app that has to do multiple calls to different webpages, each depending on the stuff gathered from a precedent call.
This would be a nightmare to do asynchronously, and I was wondering if there was any way of avoiding that.

Comment: Asynchrony is contagious. So no.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `await` keyword when you call something. Here is an example taken from https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await :

```
Future<String> createOrderMessage() async {
  var order = await fetchUserOrder();
  return 'Your order is: $order';
}

Future<String> fetchUserOrder() =>
    // Imagine that this function is
    // more complex and slow.
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 2),
      () => 'Large Latte',
    );

Future<void> main() async {
  print('Fetching user order...');
  print(await createOrderMessage());
}
```

It can only be used in `async` functions!